Copying an Excel sheet from one workbook to another in Python
Please help with Python. I can't figure out how to implement one operation. I need to move a sheet from one Excel workbook to another. It is important that this works on a computer without Excel (an alternative program is installed that can work with xlsx files). How can I do this?
I am using openpyxl. What methods are there to move sheets between xlsx workbooks? It is important for me to preserve the formulas and formatting on the sheet I am copying. I am trying to do something like this (this is a fragment):
wb_old = load_workbook(filename=file_path)
wb_new = load_workbook(filename=new_file_path)
 
for sheet in wb_old.sheetnames:
    if 'SUMM' in sheet:
        sheet_itog = wb_old[sheet]
        break

wb_new.copy_worksheet(sheet_itog)

Or this:
wb_new.move_sheet(sheet_itog, offset=1)

An error is displayed: "Cannot copy between worksheets from different workbooks."
I tried another method to implement my task using openpyxl. But also without success. The main part of the code was working. But I couldn't assign the result of an Excel formula to a variable. What methods are there in openpyxl for this?
If very briefly, any of these two options will solve my issue. But the second one is preferable:

Copy an Excel sheet from one workbook to another while preserving formulas and formatting.
Ability to save the result of an Excel formula into a variable.

Pandas does not understand Excel formulas.

he Openpyxl functions move_sheet and copy_worksheet only work within the same workbook by design. If you use Openpyxl then is cell by cell copy of the values (or formulas) and styling if you want that copied too. The examples given by @JustLearning show how. If you are just copying to a new workbook you could also consider just making a copy of the workbook and removing the unwanted Sheets (if any) from the copy
